# How to pass a string to const char* in C++?

Tags: c++, string, vector, char

I am trying to split a string on `.` in C++ and then the first splitted string I need to pass into another method which accepts `const char* key`.. But everytime I do, I always get an exception -

Below is my code -

```
istringstream iss(key);
std::vector<std::string> tokens;
std::string token;
while (std::getline(iss, token, '.')) {
    if (!token.empty()) {
        tokens.push_back(token);
    }
}

cout<<"First Splitted String: " <<tokens[0] << endl;
attr_map.upsert(tokens[0]); //this throws an exception
}
```

Below is the upsert method in AttributeMap.hh files -

```
bool upsert(const char* key);
```

And below is the exception I always get -

```
no matching function for call to AttributeMap::upsert(std::basic_string<char>&)
```

Is there anything I am missing?

Comment: That's neither a crash, nor an exception. That's a compiler error. And you resolve it by appending `.c_str()` at the appropriate place, and by additionally reading the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`c_str()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str) to get a pointer to a "null-terminated character array with data equivalent to those stored in the string" (quoting from the documentation).

```
attr_map.upsert(tokens[0].c_str()); //this won't throw an exception
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use [string::c_str](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str)

```
attr_map.upsert(tokens[0].c_str())
                        //^^^
```

You can check the reference for details on `c_str()` function.

You are getting the error because `upsert` function expects `const char*`, but you are passing `std::string`, type mismatch.